# MongoDB - How to combine findOne (in array) with aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I currently have a Mongo query that looks like this:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({ userId }).lean() || []

const contributions = await Launch.aggregate([
  { $sort: { addedAt: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: { $in: user.contributions }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      activity: 'contribution',
      launchName: '$name',
      launchId: '$_id',
      date: '$addedAt',
      content: '$description'
    }
  }
])
```

But instead of having two different Mongo queries (findOne and aggregate), how can I combine them into one query?

I tried this but it just errors out immediately in the lookup part:

```js
const contributions = await Launch.aggregate([
  { $sort: { addedAt: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'user',
      let: { id: $user.contributions },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: [$_id, $$user.contributions] } } }
      ],
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'userId',
      as: 'user'
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      activity: 'contribution',
      launchName: '$name',
      launchId: '$_id',
      date: '$addedAt',
      content: '$description'
    }
  }
])
```

I've never used the pipeline option so a little confused onn how to fix this problem?

Comment: What error did you get? Anyway, these `$user.contributions`, `$_id`, and `$$user.contributions` should be enclosed with quotes. So that your aggregation query will be a valid JSON/BSON document.

Comment: I keep trying different variations but basically the error is always that some variable is undefined. Ill try putting quotes now

Comment: with the quotes, the error is `Use of undefined variable: user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enclose these `$user.contributions`, `$_id` with quotes in order to make the query valid.
2. Since you declare the `id` variable with the value of `user.contributions`. You should use the variable with `$$id` instead of `$$user.contributions`.
3. I don't think the `localField` and `foreignField` are needed as you are mapping/joining with pipeline.

Your aggregation query should be looked as below:

```js
const contributions = await Launch.aggregate([
  { $sort: { addedAt: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'user',
      let: { id: "$user.contributions" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$id"] } } }
      ],
      as: 'user'
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      activity: 'contribution',
      launchName: '$name',
      launchId: '$_id',
      date: '$addedAt',
      content: '$description'
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Wow that was fast and it worked perfect

Comment: You answered my original question already so you don't have to take the time to answer this one unless you want to. I am getting this error `$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing` and I looked it up and saw that I should use `$ifNull` but when doing so, the program no longer errors out but it returns ALL results rather than just the matched results. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. MongoDB `$lookup` perform the LEFT JOIN concept in SQL. To perform the (INNER) JOIN, you need to filter which `user` is not an empty array. Hope this helps. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bFxOYb7svHP)